# Performing tasks in a given time

Tags: c#

I am creating a program to perform certain tasks every "x" minute.

For example:

```
Task A: every 10 minutes (this task takes 5 minutes to complete)
Task B: every 10 minutes (this task takes 5 minutes to complete)
Task C: every 1 hour (this task takes 30 mins to complete)
```

I'm having a bit of trouble getting the program to wait for each task, I'm using Sleep () to hold the wait, however, the time is not being accurate.

I'm running the process on separate threads.

```
public void Job() {
 while (true) {
  MyClass bot = null;
  try {
   bot = new MyClass(Accounts.FirstOrDefault());
   bot.TwoCaptchaApi = "...";
   bot.GridView = gridLogs;

   bot.Login();

   if (Task1)
    bot.Task1();

   if (Task2)
    bot.Task2();

   if (Task3)
    bot.Task();

   bot.Quit();

   bot.Log("Aguardando....");
  } catch (ThreadAbortException) {
   bot ? .Quit();
  } catch (Exception) {
   bot ? .Quit();
   Job();
  }
  Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).TotalMilliseconds));
  bot.Log("Tempo de espera terminado!");
 }
}
```

This means that I am using is not working well ... I do not know if using DateTime () would be the best way ... in case initialize a global variable and store the date and time of the last activity of each task

```
DateTime LastActivity = DateTime.Now;
if (LastActivity.AddHours (1)> DateTime.Now)
```

Comment: I highly suggest you to look at a proper package for this. Quartz.NET is a pretty easy way to solve this

Comment: You can pass a `TimeSpan` object directly to the [`Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Thread_Sleep_System_TimeSpan_) overload: `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));`